# union returns 2 rows in table instead of one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table in my database , and I am trying to get 2 sets of value and put them in a union.
Here is the table. [image]
My union basically has two terms where interest_payment > 0 and interest_paid > 0 ,  if interest_payment is greater than zero, it takes that row and adds it with the next row, and if the next row has interest_payment > 0 it adds it with that row, but if interest_payment < 0 , it should add interest_paid in that same row. But Right now when I run the query I get it this.
Basically the netInterest shouldn't show Null since I am using sum, so it should return me just one row.

[image]

here is the sql for all this.

```
Select sum(investedMoney) as investMoney , sum(estimatedEarning) as estimatedEarning , sum(NetInterest) as NetInterest, Eurosymbol
                from
                (
                select  sum(round(a.Amount * e.average_rate / f.average_rate, 2)) as investedMoney ,
                        sum(round((d.interest_payment + d.overdue_payment) * e.average_rate / f.average_rate, 2)) as estimatedEarning,
                        0 as NetInterest,
                        c.symbol as Eurosymbol
                from   investment a
                inner join money_offer b
                on a.ORIG_ID = b.investment_orig_id and b.UPDATE_DT is null
                inner   join payment_plan d 
                on d.offer_orig_id = b.ORIG_ID and d.interest_payment > 0 and d.UPDATE_DT is null
                inner   join currency c 
                        on  d.currency = c.ID 
                inner join exchange_rates e 
                        on  e.currency_id = a.Currency
                inner join exchange_rates f 
                        on  f.currency_id = a.Currency
                where   a.Owner = 533  and
                                a.UPDATE_DT is null

                        union 


                select  0 as investedMoney ,
                        0 as estimatedEarning,
                        sum(round((d.interest_paid+ d.overdue_paid) * e.average_rate / f.average_rate, 2)) as NetInterest,
                        c.symbol as Eurosymbol
                from   investment a
                inner join money_offer b
                on a.ORIG_ID = b.investment_orig_id and b.UPDATE_DT is null
                inner   join payment_plan d 
                on d.offer_orig_id = b.ORIG_ID and d.interest_paid > 0 and d.UPDATE_DT is null
                inner   join currency c 
                        on  d.currency = c.ID 
                inner join exchange_rates e 
                        on  e.currency_id = a.Currency
                inner join exchange_rates f 
                        on  f.currency_id = a.Currency
                where   a.Owner = 533  and
                                a.UPDATE_DT is null
                )tmptbl
                group by Eurosymbol;
```

Comment: But `Eurosymbol` is different on those two rows, so the `group by` won't combine them.

Comment: How is it different? I am getting the first one as same way as the second select

Comment: As Gordon says, `Eurosymbol` is `NULL` on one row, and '€' on the other. As you're grouping by that column, you'll get two rows because there are two different values. Presumably your differing `ORIG_ID` in the two rows of your table link through to the differing currency symbol values.

Comment: @MattGibson the `ORIG_ID` I used is basically the same in both the selects.

Comment: All we can see is the results you're showing us, which show two different values of `Eurosymbol`. What happens if you run each `SELECT` of your `UNION` separately? Do you see the results you would expect? We can't really tell what's going on without either a simpler example, or your full data (we can't see your `owner` values, for example.)

Comment: You always want exactly one row in the output (for the given `where` condition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In either the case of `d.interest_payment > 0` or `d.interest_paid > 0` you store a different Currency in the `payment_plan` table. My guess is that you have dummy ID to indicate "no currency". Assuming that you have a NULL value stored for that particular dummy currency in `currency.symbol`, you could just take the `max` of it in your overall query.

Also, I think for your purposes you should combine the `union` queries into one. This way you can deal with cases where both conditions are true in the same record: they will then not be duplicated. The distinction between the two types of figures can be made with a `case when` construct, like this:

```
  select      sum(case when d.interest_payment > 0 
                    then round(a.Amount * e.average_rate / f.average_rate, 2) 
                    else 0 
                  end) as investedMoney,
              sum(case when d.interest_payment > 0 
                    then round((d.interest_payment + d.overdue_payment) 
                               * e.average_rate / f.average_rate, 2)
                    else 0 
                  end) as estimatedEarning,
              sum(case when d.interest_paid > 0 
                    then round((d.interest_paid + d.overdue_paid) 
                               * e.average_rate / f.average_rate, 2)
                    else 0
                  end) as NetInterest,
              max(c.symbol) as Eurosymbol
  from        investment a
  inner join  money_offer b
          on  a.ORIG_ID = b.investment_orig_id and b.UPDATE_DT is null
  inner join  payment_plan d 
          on  d.offer_orig_id = b.ORIG_ID and d.UPDATE_DT is null
          and (d.interest_payment > 0 or d.interest_paid > 0)
  inner join  currency c 
          on  d.currency = c.ID 
  inner join  exchange_rates e 
          on  e.currency_id = a.Currency
  inner join  exchange_rates f 
          on  f.currency_id = a.Currency
  where       a.Owner = 533  
      and     a.UPDATE_DT is null
```

You should also review why you join the exact same record twice from `exchange_rates` (as `e` and `f`) which makes the expression `e.average_rate / f.average_rate` always evaluate to 1 (assuming the rates are never zero).

Comment: I joined both the records since I thought there were two different criteria, and also I did not know there is a way to use case when, but thanks , learned something new today!!!! I will make the other necessary          adjustments!